# How to retrieve all email messages over *** characters long?

Tags: email, search, message, blogs

I always had trouble updating blogs i wrote, but it occured to me that whenever people ask me something I can give really long replies that could easily become articles.

However there`s not a feature in GMail or any other mail app for that matter, that enables me to search by message length.

Will I have to write a script to retrieve all messages and then process them or is there an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you could do is to use e.g. MS Office Outlook - I know they have a feature to create rules where you can specify to retrieve, move and what-not with e-mails sized over X ammount of kilobytes.

Might be an option?

Comment: Maybe an ultimate option. I`m a linux user. =( Also, would it be possible to exclude emails with attachments? Even if it would, it wouldn`t be quite the solution I`m looking for, since there might be some messages with attachments still valuable. What I really need is to count characters.

Comment: Well, I'm not too sure when it comes to an Linux enviroment. But doesn't Mozilla have a GUI-client for Linux? But whatever you decide to use, I suggest you check out "Rules".

Comment: Ok, i`ll give that a try. Maybe it actually works better anyway. I`ll was trying to access gmail trough IMAP via PHP.